# Error al insertar fechas en SQL Server

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, date

espero me puedan brindar una orientación, sucede que de un formulario estoy mandando un conjunto de campos, y al tratar de guardar el formulario, me sale este error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC > Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a date. in C:\xampp\htdocs\acacypac-new\main\CONTROLES\code\Creditos\Models\Credito.php:240
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\acacypac-new\main\CONTROLES\code\Creditos\Models\Credito.php(240): PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\acacypac-new\main\CONTROLES\code\Creditos\controlesGuardarCredito.php(177): Credito->guardarRemesa('NULL', '4', 'Sub')
> #2 {main}
> thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\acacypac-new\main\CONTROLES\code\Creditos\Models\Credito.php** on line **240**

He probado distintos formatos de fecha, por el momento tengo este, que según investigué es el que recibe por defecto sql server:

```
if(!empty($this->fechaOtorgamiento))
        {
            $this->fechaOtorgamiento = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->fechaOtorgamiento));
        }

        if(!empty($this->fechaCancelacion))
        {
            $this->fechaCancelacion = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->fechaCancelacion));
        }
```

Acá mando a llamar el procedimiento almacenado (quité algunos valores para no extender mucho el código):

```
function guardarRemesa ( $logs, $idApartado, $tipoApartado )
    {
        $respuesta = null; $dbId = 0;

        $query = 'EXEC controles_spGuardarCreditos :id, :codigoCliente, :idEmpresa, :empresa, :idTipoCredito, :numeroDePrestamo, :monto, :idAgencia, :idUsuario, :ipOrdenador, :idApartado, :tipoApartado, :logs, :dbId, 
                                                   :fechaOtorgamiento, :fechaCancelacion,:idEjecutivo, :pagaduria, :idDestinoInterno, :idPlazoInterno, :idTasaInterna,
                                                   :cuotaInterna, :idGarantiaInterna, :idSistemaFinanciero, :idLineaFinanciera, :idDestinoExterno, :montoExterno, :cuotaExterna, :idTasaExterna, :idPlazoExterno,
                                                   :idGarantiaExterna, :respuesta';
        $result = $this->conexion->prepare($query, [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL]);
        $result->bindParam(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':codigoCliente', $this->codigoCliente, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':fechaOtorgamiento', $this->fechaOtorgamiento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':fechaCancelacion', $this->fechaCancelacion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
       
        $result->bindParam(':respuesta', $respuesta, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
        

        $result->execute();


        if ( $respuesta == 'EXITO')
        {
            return (object)['status' => true, 'respuesta' => $respuesta,  'id' => $dbId];
        } else
        {
            return (object)['status' => false, 'respuesta' => $respuesta, 'id' => $dbId ];
        }
    }
```

Acá capturo el contenido de las fechas a través de los inputs

```
$fechaOtorgamiento = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['txtFechaOtorgamiento']['value']));            
    $fechaCancelacion = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['txtFechaCancelacion']['value']));
```

Les comparto un fragmento de mi procedimiento almacenado

```
@fechaOtorgamiento DATE,
    @fechaCancelacion DATE,
 -- Ahora, insertar o actualizar en controles_detalleCreditos
            IF @codigoCliente IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                -- Verificar si existe un registro para el cliente actual
                DECLARE @detalleCreditosId INT;
                SELECT @detalleCreditosId = id FROM controles_detalleCreditos WHERE idCliente = @codigoCliente;

                IF @detalleCreditosId IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    -- No existe un registro, insertar uno nuevo
                    INSERT INTO controles_detalleCreditos (
                        idUsuario,
                        idCliente,
                        fechaOtorgamiento,
                        fechaCancelacion,
                        idEjecutivo,
                        cuotaInterna,
                        pagaduria,
                        idDestinoInterno,
                        idPlazoInterno,
                        idTasaInterna,
                        idGarantiaInterna,
                        idSistemaFinanciero,
                        idLineaFinanciera,
                        idDestinoExterno,
                        montoExterno,
                        cuotaExterna,
                        idTasaExterna,
                        idPlazoExterno,
                        idGarantiaExterna
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        @idUsuario,
                        @codigoCliente,
                        @fechaOtorgamiento,
                        @fechaCancelacion,
                        @idEjecutivo,
                        @cuotaInterna,
                        @pagaduria,
                        @idDestinoInterno,
                        @idPlazoInterno,
                        @idTasaInterna,
                        @idGarantiaInterna,
                        @idSistemaFinanciero,
                        @idLineaFinanciera,
                        @idDestinoExterno,
                        @montoExterno,
                        @cuotaExterna,
                        @idTasaExterna,
                        @idPlazoExterno,
                        @idGarantiaExterna
                    );
                END
```

Y en el procedimiento almacenado ambos campos de fecha "fechaOtorgamiento" y "fechaCancelacion" los espera como tipo date, Ya intenté con formato 'Y-m-d' y 'd-m-Y', también seteando english language y spanish language en el motor de base de datos, les agradezco cualquier iluminación

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solventar el problema es que tenía los parámetros en distinto orden al esperado en el procedimiento almacenado, por lo que me arrojaba un error de tipado.